# My native component is undefined when installed - react native

Tags: android, react-native, npm

im building my own npm package because need to implement a native sdk, started the package following docs: [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup), created all the native views in android side and works, published to npm and installed to my current project, problem is when im about to create the native component i get the error: `MyViewManager is undefined`, its the name from android, dont know why.

the package starts with the index.js, so here its:

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

const MyViewManager =  requireNativeComponent('MyViewManager');
const MediumRectangleCube =  requireNativeComponent('MediumRectangleCube');

export { MyViewManager, MediumRectangleCube };
```

then in my project to use the package:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { MyViewManager } from "react-native-innity-remaster";
import { Text, UIManager, findNodeHandle} from "react-native";

const createMediumRectangle = (viewId) =>
    UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
    viewId,
    UIManager.MyViewManager.Commands.create.toString(),
[viewId]
);

export const Test = () => {

    const ref = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const viewId = findNodeHandle(ref.current);
        createAD(viewId);
      }, []);
  
    const createAD = (viewId) => {
        createMediumRectangle(viewId);
    }

    return (
        <Text>hola</Text>
    )
}
```

but still getting:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.UIManager.MyViewManager.Commands')
```

Comment: Is your component like an installed dependency? Or is it a local native component? I'm asking this because you have this import on your code: `import { MyViewManager } from "react-native-innity-remaster";`

Comment: @LuísMestre its an installed dependecy, npm package build by myself